# 400 Bad Request on Push Notification Symfony / Sly Notification Pusher

Tags: android, ios, symfony, push-notification

In my symfony project i use the bundle Sly Notification Pusher to send pushnotification on ios and android device, until today everything work great ! 
But right now i have a big problem, when i send a push notification i have this error : 
["400 bad request : invalid message "](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7GnOa.png)

When i try to debug i have see that the push function return this error.
["3" not display in debug mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbiPq.png)

I have read the documentation and follow the syntax but the problem is the same, our application used this code since 1 year and today we can't use push notification due to this problem.

Please help us !

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Can you dump the message you are trying to send it may contain invalid characters or it exceeded the maximum size allowed for a notification (payload is 256 bytes).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i think is not the problem because even if i create a message with 1 characters the error is return. Here is what is returned : object(Sly\NotificationPusher\Model\Message)#948 (2) { ["text":"Sly\NotificationPusher\Model\Message":private]=> string(27) "CentoLive : My notification" ["options":protected]=> array(2) { ["body"]=> string(8) "Hello..." ["title"]=> string(27) "CentoLive : My notification" } }